# Problem with changing class in React using useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state, sidebar

So I'm new to **React** and I've been practicing on this website that I'm creating,
anyway, what I've been trying to do is to make a simple **sidebar**, I'm using **stateHooks**,
so this is declaring the states and the click handler :

```
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
    const handleToggle = () => {
      setMenu(!menu);
    };
```

and then i added the **onClick** listener and the **classname** change as the state changes :

```
    <div className="header__menu__toggler">
      <MenuIcon
        onClick={handleToggle}
        className={`header__menu__bars ${menu ? "menuOn" : ""}`}
       />
       <ClearIcon
        onClick={handleToggle}
        className={`header__menu__times ${menu ? "menuOn" : ""}`}
       />
    </div>
```

and this is the **css** part of it :

```
    .header__menu__bars{
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    .header__menu__times{
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    .header__menu__bars.menuOn{
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    .header__menu__times.menuOn{
        transform: scale(2);
    }
```

but seems like this method doesn't work, so anyone can help me with it or have another method to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected behavior? What is this code doing instead?

Comment: You need to pass `onClick`  to a div or actual element if not yet. Can you share the code for `MenuIcon` and `ClearIcon`?

Comment: Downvoted.... cause this question isn't clear.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've posted. You need to show the `MenuIcon` and/or `ClearIcon` components, you're probably not passing the through the click

Answer (score 0):

First, i would recommend using "clsx" (npm i clsx)

```
`header__menu__bars ${menu ? "menuOn" : ""}`
// changed to
clsx('header__menu__bars', menu && 'menuOn')
```

Then

```
setMenu(!menu);
// When using current state, it is better to pass function
setMenu((oldMenuState) => !oldMenuState)
```

Finally check MenuIcon and ClearIcon, if you pass onClick down.